# socket io cannot use foreign machines in the same LAN

Tags: iis, next.js, websocket, windows-firewall

socket io is available on the server. But I can't use a foreign machine in the same LAN. But if I turn off the firewall, it can work. So I created a firewall rule to allow port 3000, but it hasn't yet.

---

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
cors: {
origin: 'http://192.168.2.38',
methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
credentials: true,
},
});

```
  httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
  });
```

---

```
const socket = socketIoClient('http://192.168.2.38:3000', {
  withCredentials: true,
  transports: ['websocket'],
});
```

---

access through the IP address of the server at port 80.

I want to be able to use socket io from external machines in the same LAN even with the firewall turned off.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ if you configured things properly, Socket.IO should work through port 80.

Comment: Hello, thank you for coming to help.

The socket io allows me to connect through port 3000 in port 80 as the website. I don't know if doing this is correct or not, but if I turn off the firewall, everything will work normally.

Comment: The common practice is to only open port 80/443 on firewall for your web sites (HTTP/HTTPS). IIS takes care of the incoming traffic with its built-in security feature. You shouldn't open port 3000, however, as Node.js's built-in HTTP server wasn't designed to be that secure.

Comment: If i use
httpServer.listen(80, () => {
   console.log('Server is running on port 80');
});

I will receive a response that port 80 is not available because this is the work of the website itself. How do I fix it?

Comment: I already wrote everything in the blog post in my first comment. Your Node.js HTTP server should be put behind IIS if hosting on Windows.